Как лучше всего добавить cronJob в keubernetes?
есть проект на React в облаке k8s. Инфраструткура разворачивается через terraform и следит за состоянием через ArgoCD. Появилась необходимость в проекте запускать скрипт раз час. Как лучше всего добавить cronJob в проект? Дописать cron в конфиг terraform и задеплоить?

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/
